# Compatable with LINX 10B Tablet

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

My LINX 10B has been updated to Windows 10 and like a lot of other Windows 10 updaters I am suffering from "Critical Process" errors. Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.

Specification:-

CPU Family  Intel Baytrail-T 
Processor, Z3735F, 
speed 1.8 GHz.

Internal Flash 32GB.

Memory Size 2048 MB.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Yes you can install it, although your specs are too low for Unity, try http://xubuntu.org/ same OS, different desktop, lower requirements, I can't speak for the touch experience though. Install instructions http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can install ubuntu 14.04lts or 15.04 ensure that you download a version that is 32bit and use the micro usb to usb cable to plug into a usb3 hub plug keyboard mouse and dvd drive or pen stick and reboot device and then press del to enter bios and force to boot from cd or penstick do a live boot and test then click install (note some versions of linx may require write protection switching off in bios)

Comment: (The OP is asking about a specific Intel processor,  not generic processors)